# Return a model from a custom query without hitting the database

Tags: sql, django, django-models, model

I have a custom query which eventually returns a list of objects. I need the function to return the actual objects but I don't want to hit the database twice for every query since it's already an expensive query. How can i return a model instance without hitting the db?

NB: I presume doing something like the following will actually create a new instance of a different model?

```
return [Object(pk=row[0]) for row in results]
```

NB: I also presume that this will hit the database, on function return

```
return [Object.objects.get(pk=row[0]) for row in results]
```

Comment: Why can you not return a queryset?

Comment: @lazerscience: I am _guessing_ that he finds the SQL too complicated/impossible to duplicate using the Django API.

Comment: @lazerscience: yeah, it's as Manoj says, the SQL just can't be done using django ORM. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Django 1.2+ you can use the [`raw()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw) method to return list of `Model` instances using the results of a custom query. Something like this in your case:

```
query = "<your query goes here>"
Object.objects.raw(query)
```

Comment: Oh awesome. I've just switched to 1.2 and must have missed that in the release notes!